# Sidebar dropped out of column-Div, how can I put it back there via XML?

Tags: magento2, xml

I have the normal sidebar on a blog page (we are using a module for creating blog structure in the backend), the layout of the page is `layout="2columns-right"`.

The DOM is the following:

```
<main class="maincontent">
   <div class="columns">
       <div class="column main">

       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar sidebar-additional">

   </div>
</main>
```

The desired DOM output is this:

```
<main class="maincontent">
   <div class="columns">
       <div class="column main">

       </div>
       <div class="sidebar sidebar-additional">

       </div>
   </div>
</main>
```

How can I achieve this, by using XML and preferably the `<move>`-Term?

I have no idea why the sidebar drops out of its scope, every other CMS site is absolutely okay and there is no XML telling this specific page to render the Sidebar somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy.

```
<move element="sidebar.main" destination="columns" />
```